# Getting data from the $.getJSON() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I'm writing a web application and need to initialize some parameters that I'm pulling via the $.getJSON() method.

```
$.getJSON("../config/", function(data)
{
     console.debug(data);
}
```

Now since these values will be used globally throughout the script and will not be triggering an event directly (which is the only implementation of $.getJSON() I could find in the documentation), how can I returning or retrieve this callback data?

Comment: I don't get your problem here, $.getJSON 2nd argument is a callback function, which is called once the request is complete and successful.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data from getJSON?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your best bet is to stick with the callback technique.

There are 2 real ways to make it work, both are essentially the same.

```
$.getJSON("../config/", function(data) {
        SomeObject.config = data; 
        SomeObject.load();   # assuming load tells some-object that it now has data and to get cracking
});
```

or

```
$.getJSON("../config/", function(data) {
        SomeObject.load( data );   # SomeObject sets itself up and starts doing its thing
});
```

Trying to use $.getJSON in a synchronous way ( ie: having it return a value ) will only end in tears and misery for both you *and* the people using your site, because Synchronous connections have a tendency to block the entire UI. :)

As it stands, doing anything like this asynchronously

```
var i = null;                              #1
$.getJSON("../config/", function(data) {   #2
        i = data;                          #3
});                                        #4
some_function_with(i);                     #5
```

Will not work, because line 5 is almost guaranteed to execute before line 3.

Comment: Safeguarded all caveats concerning synchronous requests, in case you really need to do it that way, you'll need to use the "lower level" $.ajax({ ... , dataType: "json", async: false )}. In the example above, that'll guarantee #3 execution prior to #5.

Answer (score 3):

Kent Fredric: I'm not sure if your approach might be better, so if your method is better let me know how and I'll accept your solution over my own, but this is how I did it:

```
 var my_data = null;

$.ajax(
{
    url: "../config/",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        my_data = data;
    }
});
```

Also thank you RichieHindle, I didn't know it was possible to replace variables outside of functions without return.

Comment: synchronous requests block the browser, so in the event of a server timeout, the browser might get hung, ... indefinitely. While Synchronous requests are taking place, the page will not respond to user input.

Comment: @Kent: They don't block my browser. There is no difference between a synchronous request and a normal, standard page load; if the data you're pulling via AJAX is critical, I see no reason at all to avoid synchronous requests -- you probably _don't want_ the user providing inputs during this time anyway!

Comment: Im just taking it *straight* from the documentation: "Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active."  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And yes, there is a difference, a sync request works like an inline <script> + document.write call, where the stuff after it can't be used until after that script is finished. ( Ie: the document rendering and the script execution are synchronous too )

And if you block inside a <script> tag indefinitely, the UI tends to not respond all too well.